# how to source a bash script from inside a csh script

Tags: bash, scripting

```
  #!/bin/csh -x
   exec bash
   source ~arovit/RTM_test/unit_RTM/fail.10/failure.001.sh
   exec csh
   <script continues...>
```

is there any other way to do so ?

Comment: As you already know, what you show won't work; the first `exec` replaces the script with a (probably interactive) bash.

Comment: See: [C Shell Programming Considered Harmful](http://faqs.cs.uu.nl/na-dir/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the whole purpose of the bash script is to export the relevant env variables, I'd suggest you run the script as bash, the call the following script using `csh`. E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~arovit/RTM_test/unit_RTM/fail.10/failure.001.sh
csh -x your_csh_script.sh
```

If the bash script isn't exporting vars, and is simply performing some tasks, then do it the other way round:

```
#!/bin/csh -x
bash ~arovit/RTM_test/unit_RTM/fail.10/failure.001.sh
<script continues...>
```

Comment: No it doesnot involve exporting env variable.

Comment: @aro: if the failure.001.sh script does not involve setting environment, why do you need to source it instead of just running it?

Comment: @Shawin :It works ! Thanks . Can you tell me what was wrong in my solution?

Comment: Okay lets consider a scenario where both are setting and using some env variables or in otherwords exporting env variables then what would be the solution?

Comment: @aro in your script, the issue is that `exec bash` will start up an instance of bash and passing on control to it. The remainder of the script is run as usual (using csh) only when that instance ends.

Comment: If both are setting and exporting variables, I'd suggest you either rewrite one of it to use solely `bash` or `csh`, or if that's not possible, then pull the exporting of variables into a another script and use the method I listed in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```
#!/bin/csh
bash -c 'source bash_source; exec csh'
```